# Аналог приложения "телефон" на Java под Android

Tags: java, android

В инете есть информация как из своего приложения на Android можно позвонить используя стандартное приложение телефон.

Как это можно сделать без его использования, то есть как сделать звонок, откуда читать входящий поток и куда записывать исходящий поток, как кодировать и можно ли реализовать конференцию?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Позвонить через свое приложение можно таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:900..." ));
startActivity(intent);
```

при этом нужно дать разрешение в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters). Вероятнее всего сам звонок будет осуществляться при помощи встроенного системного приложения. Изменить его вряд ли получится. По поводу конференции - есть такая штука как [InCallUI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/) и для создания связки двух звонком используется такая штука в системе [InCallPresenter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/+/master/src/com/android/incallui/InCallPresenter.java)

Вот [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call), и [вот есть подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950962/9363441), где так же представлена полезная информация по вашей проблеме.